# webpack-dev-middleware not serving my client

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

I have a nodejs app on the server-side and a vue app on the client side

I want my server side to serve my client when accessing certain urls (for example '/')

my client is under `project_root/frontend` and my server is under `project_root/server`

This is my `server/app.js` file:

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

const app = express();

if(process.env['FUNDME_DEV']) {
  app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist')
  }))
} else {
  //production
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist')));
}
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started, listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

My webpack.config.js file is mostly guesswork and copying from the one the vue-cli made for me when I created the frontend, so it might be wrong, but the output when running the server in dev mode (`export FUNDME_DEV=1`) says it compiled successfully.

However, when I try to access my app, I'm getting "Cannot GET /", the middleware serves nothing :(

I don't know what am I missing, or how my webpack config should look exactly, I found none of the other similar questions helpful.

what am I suppose to do?

Comment: webpack devMiddleware does not serve "BUILT" files, they build in memory and serve them from memory. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: yes. I'm not expecting it to serve static files, just the opposite. I want it to compile in memory so changes while I develop would be applied quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

const app = express();

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { // you don't have to compile the content first, just start this as dev.
  app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: '/' // <--- this has to be the same publicPath that you inserted on your webpack config, otherwise you could leave this as /
  }))
} else {
  //production
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist')));
}
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started, listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: And what path should I put my webpack config? I'm not sure what role it plays if the intention is to serve the result from memory without writing to disk

Comment: leave that as /. You webpack config goes on the compiler, then goes to middleware

Comment: with the public path set to '/' it does serve _something_, just not what i want. it serves a compiled js file, but no index.html. I'm still missing something

Comment: I added `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, and now I get an html and I _sort of_ see my app. But it's displayed badly, like maybe some css is missing or vuetify (which I use) was not compiled/delivered correctly. Any tips?

Comment: generate a build and see what is the path inserted to the link tag (css) on your html. It is a good start